# How to deal with system is computationally singular error when running model in R?

Tags: r, nlp

I am using the new `conText` package in `R` to run a context embedding regression model. Below I provide the code that I have written thus far:

```
# load speeches
speeches <- read.csv("convocation6.csv")
speeches$crimea <- ifelse(speeches$Date >= "2014-02-18", 1, 0)
speeches$ruling <- ifelse(speeches$party_id == "UR", 1, 0)
speeches$party <- ifelse(speeches$party_id == "UR", "Ruling", "Opposition")

# create corpus
# preparing speeches
speeches$text <- as.character(speeches$text)
speeches$docnames <- speeches$name
speeches_corpus <- quanteda::corpus(speeches, docid_field ="X", docnames = 
                                      docnames, text_field ="text")

# tokenize corpus removing unnecessary (i.e. semantically uninformative) elements
toks <- tokens(speeches_corpus, remove_punct = T, remove_symbols = T, remove_numbers = T, 
               remove_separators = T)

# clean out stopwords and words with 2 or fewer characters
toks_nostop <- tokens_select(toks, pattern = stopwords("ru", source = "snowball"), selection = "remove",
                             min_nchar = 3
)

# only use features that appear at least 5 times in the corpus
feats <- dfm(toks_nostop, tolower = T, verbose = TRUE) %>% dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 5) %>% 
  featnames()

# leave the pads so that non-adjacent words will not become adjacent
toks <- tokens_select(toks_nostop, feats, padding = TRUE)

# build a tokenized corpus of contexts sorrounding the target term 'economy'
economy_toks <- tokens_context(x = toks, pattern = "экономик*", window = 6L)

# build document-feature matrix
economy_dfm <- dfm(economy_toks)
economy_dfm[1:3, 1:3]

# construct the feature co-occurrence matrix for our toks object (see above)
toks_fcm <- fcm(toks, context = "window", window = 6, count = "frequency", tri = FALSE)

# estimate glove model using text2vec
glove <- GlobalVectors$new(rank = 300, x_max = 10, learning_rate = 0.05)
wv_main <- glove$fit_transform(toks_fcm, n_iter = 10, convergence_tol = 0.001, n_threads = parallel::detectCores())  # set to 'parallel::detectCores()' to use all available cores

wv_context <- glove$components
local_glove <- wv_main + t(wv_context)  # word vectors

local_transform <- compute_transform(x = toks_fcm, pre_trained = local_glove, weighting = "log")

economy_dem_local <- dem(x = economy_dfm, pre_trained = local_glove, transform = TRUE, 
                         transform_matrix = local_transform, verbose = TRUE)

# take the column average to get a single "corpus-wide" embedding
economy_wv_local <- colMeans(economy_dem_local)

# find nearest neighbors for overall immigraiton embedding
find_nns(economy_wv_local, pre_trained = local_glove, N = 10, candidates = economy_dem_local@features)

# we limit candidates to features in our corpus
feats <- featnames(dfm(economy_toks))

#### NEAREST NEIGHBORS ECONOMY 

# compare nearest neighbors between groups
set.seed(2021L)
economy_party_ncs <- get_ncs(x = economy_toks,
                           N = 10,
                           groups = docvars(economy_toks, 'party'),
                           pre_trained = local_glove,
                           transform = TRUE,
                           transform_matrix = local_transform,
                           bootstrap = TRUE,
                           num_bootstraps = 10,
                           as_list = TRUE)

# nearest neighbors of "economy" for ruling party
economy_party_ncs[["Ruling"]]

# nearest neighbors of "economy" for opposition party
economy_party_ncs[["Opposition"]]

#### CONTEXT EMBEDDING REGRESSION ECONOMY 
docvars(toks)
# two factor covariates
set.seed(123)
model1 <- conText(formula = "экономик*" ~ crimea + ruling,
                  data = toks,
                  pre_trained = local_glove,
                  transform = TRUE, transform_matrix = local_transform,
                  bootstrap = TRUE, num_bootstraps = 10,
                  permute = TRUE, num_permutations = 100,
                  window = 6, case_insensitive = TRUE,
                  verbose = FALSE)
```

Whenever I attempt to run `model1` I receive the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(t(X_mat) %*% X_mat) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 0
```

This error goes away when I run the model with just the `crimea` variable. I'm not sure what is going on with the `Ruling` variable. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? This is a simple dummy variable. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: look at `with(toks, table(crimea, Ruling))`. Perhaps you've got a collinear association.

Comment: I've looked into this, and there are no collinear associations.